# Sails.js: which modules to use for unit testing?

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm new to sails.js and node.js. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to setup unit testing. In Kraken.js for example, there is already a test/ folder setup upon generate, and it looks like it uses mocha.

But nothing like this comes pre-packaged with sails.js. I'm wondering what's the best way to structure it, which dependencies do I need to add (should I be using karma, jasmine, mocha, protractor, ...), and how to automate everything (ie. to run all tests using "grunt test" I suppose, or should I be running tests on every "npm start"...?)

How have you set up unit testing in your sails.js environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SailsJS is using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) as a main testing framework.
I would strongly advise you using the same technology, as it has a lot of features and can be easily integrated with various continuous integration services (e.g. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)).

Official tutorial related to SailsJS unit testing can be found here: [Testing your code](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Testing)

For DB fixtures you can use [Barrels](https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels).

Comment: Can I also use this for E2E tests with AngularJS, or do I have to use something like Protractor?

Comment: I think the way you are recommending to test sails is not about unit testing. Because, if I have promises - it will involve them in testing too.
The only way I found to make unit tests in sails - is to use SinonJS lib.
Please correct me if I'm wrong in something.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using "grunt test", it created an unnecessary dependency.

Instead uses "npm test" that is already installed on all node.js environment.
Or a makefile (make test).

It is usual to place the tests in the "test" directory.

Mocha is a very good test runner (also used by SailJS). I use Mocha with Unit.js (http://unitjs.com) that provides everything I need for unit testing.